# hide something in single page if current author has only one post

Tags: author

I'm trying to hide a div in a single page if the current author of the post has only one post. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
<?php hide or don't display if current author has only 1 post ?>
<div>blah blah blah</div>
<?php end ?>
```

Comment: if they have fewer than 1 post, how can you be viewing a single post by that author?

Comment: i mean 1 post only then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`count_user_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) will give you the number of posts for an author. [`get_the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) gives you the user's ID. Note that this needs to be in The Loop to get the correct user.

```
if( 1 < count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 'post' ) ) {
    echo '<div>blah blah blah</div>';
}
```

Comment: <?php if( 1 < count_user_posts( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 'post' ) ) { ?><div>blah blah blah</div><?php } ?> works too